# Converting a [(Int, Seq[Double])] RDD to LabeledPoint

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have an RDD of the following format and would like to convert it into a LabeledPoint RDD in order to process it in mllib :

```
Test: RDD[(Int, Seq[Double])] = Array((1,List(1.0,3.0,8.0),(2,List(3.0, 3.0,8.0),(1,List(2.0,3.0,7.0),(1,List(5.0,5.0,9.0))
```

I tried with map

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
Test.map(x=> LabeledPoint(x._1, Vectors.sparse(x._2)))
```

but I get this error

```
mllib.linalg.Vector cannot be applied to (Seq[scala.Double])
```

So presumably the Seq element needs to be converted first but I don't know into what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

- label should be `Double` not `Int`
- `SparseVector` requires number of elements, indices and values
- none of the vector constructors accepts list of `Double`
- your data looks dense not sparse

One possible solution:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(
    (1, List(1.0,3.0,8.0)),
    (2, List(3.0, 3.0,8.0)),
    (1, List(2.0,3.0,7.0)),
    (1, List(5.0,5.0,9.0))))

rdd.map { case (k, vs) => 
  LabeledPoint(k.toDouble, Vectors.dense(vs.toArray))
}
```

and another:

```
rdd.collect { case (k, v::vs) =>
  LabeledPoint(k.toDouble, Vectors.dense(v, vs: _*)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can notice in [LabeledPoint's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint) its constructor receives a `Double` as a label and a [Vector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) as features ([DenseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector) or [SparseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector)). However, if you take a look in both inherited classes' constructors they receive an `Array`, therefore you need to convert your `Seq` to `Array`.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors, DenseVector}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array((1, Seq(1.0,3.0,8.0)), 
                               (2, Seq(3.0, 3.0,8.0)),
                               (1, Seq(2.0,3.0, 7.0)),
                               (1, Seq(5.0, 5.0, 9.0))))
val x = rdd.map{
    case (a: Int, b:Seq[Double]) => LabeledPoint(a, new DenseVector(b.toArray))
}

x.take(2).foreach(println)

//(1.0,[1.0,3.0,8.0])
//(2.0,[3.0,3.0,8.0])
```